# using PDO object for a Select query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am a beginner in PDO. I am following a tutorial to learning PDO. I want to use a simple select statement to fetch id of users.

but when I run `index.php` it dont show any `echo` ! where is my wrong ?

I have four files :

config => setting username and password...

DB_Connect :

```
class DB_Connect {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {

    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // $this->close();
    }

    // Connecting to database
    public function connect() {
        require_once 'include/config.php';
        try {
            $hostname = DB_HOST ;
            $dbname   = DB_DATABASE;
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $dbh;
    }



}
```

---

DB_Functions :

```
class DB_Functions {

    private $db;

    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $this->db = new DB_Connect();
        $this->db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }


    function getUsers(){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
        foreach ($this->$db->query($sql) as $row)
        {
            echo $row->id;
        }

        /*** close the database connection ***/
      //  $db = null;

    }
}
```

---

index.php

```
<?php

    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
    $qr = new DB_Functions();
    $qr->getUsers();



?>
```

Comment: `$this->$db->query($sql)` to `$this->db->query($sql)`

Comment: I changed it to db, but I have not any output yet .

Comment: Do you have connection with your database? Are you fetching your result as an object or an array? try `var_Dump($row)`

Comment: Try adding the `error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', '1');` on the top of the page and see what error u get

Comment: @ FIA2008:yes, because I have not any error.

Comment: What does `var_dump($row)` give you as output?

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty : I get these errors and warnings : http://i.stack.imgur.com/NgVWn.jpg

Comment: So its pretty clear that the connection to DB is not established. Debug that connection part and see if all the values uname,pass,host,dbname etc are properly set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

db_connect

```
class DB_Connect {
    public $dbh;
    // constructor
    function __construct() {

    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // $this->close();
    }

    // Connecting to database
    public function connect() {
        require_once 'include/config.php';
        try {
            $hostname = DB_HOST ;
            $dbname   = DB_DATABASE;
            $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

db_functions

```
class DB_Functions {

    private $db;

    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $this->db = new DB_Connect();
        $this->db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }


    function getUsers(){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
        foreach ($this->db->dbh->query($sql) as $row)
        {
            echo $row->id;
        }

        /*** close the database connection ***/
      //  $db = null;

    }
}
```

You have no database connection because you're now assigning your PDO connection to a variable. So you're connection is not accessible to the rest of your script. At least, that's what I'm thinking at the moment.

Comment: what is query function ? I must implement query function  ?

Comment: THe query functions is part of the PDO class. You can't access your PDO class because when you connect to your database using PDO, you create a local variable, which is only accessible in that single function and not in the rest of your class. Therefore you need to make your connection available to the rest of your class like this: `$this->dbh`